# Rewrite these DB2 SUBQUERY into a Join

Tags: sql, date, db2, subquery

I have some business rules that I need to query the database for. Right now the sql below are using subqueries, but I want to change each query to a join statement.

- column oditnr: the item number
- column odredt: the number of days since the order was placed
- column odbcsn: the customer #

My database is DB2, but I created a sql fiddle using mysql
http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3d10ae/3

I need to check if a customer has purchased item number 1025926 within the last 60 days 
if the query returns a result, then the customer purchased the item.

```sql
SELECT ord1.oditnr, ord1.odredt, itm.imdesc  
FROM orderdetails ord1
  LEFT JOIN items itm ON ord1.oditnr = itm.imitnr
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * 
              FROM orderdetails ord2 
              WHERE ord1.odbcsn = ord2.odbcsn 
                AND ord2.oditnr = '1022925'  
                AND odredt >= VARCHAR_FORMAT(CURRENT TIMESTAMP - 60 DAYS, 'YYYYMMDD') ) 
AND ord1.odbcsn = '11677'  
ORDER BY odredt desc ;
```

I need to check if a customer has not purchased item number 2521809 within the last 60 days 
if the query returns a result, then the customer has not purchased the item.

```
SELECT ord1.oditnr, ord1.odredt, itm.imdesc  
FROM orderdetails ord1
   LEFT JOIN items itm ON ord1.oditnr = itm.imitnr
WHERE NOT  EXISTS (SELECT * 
                   FROM orderdetails ord2 
                   WHERE ord1.odbcsn = ord2.odbcsn 
                     AND ord2.oditnr = '2521809'  
                     AND odredt >= VARCHAR_FORMAT(CURRENT TIMESTAMP - 60 DAYS, 'YYYYMMDD') ) 
AND ord1.odbcsn = '11677'  
ORDER BY odredt desc ;
```

Comment: Care to comment _why_ you need the joins?

Comment: i am using http://mistic100.github.io/jQuery-QueryBuilder/ to create an interface to build the query. subqueries are too complicated for the plugin

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I would like some help converting the 2 queries above into joins without using a subquery

Comment: Keep in mind that the join is likely to perform worse, particularly compared with `not exists`. Choosing a better tool (query builder) for the job might be a better option.

Answer (score -1):

If you cannot find another tool to use that supports subqueries, you can try the following:

```
SELECT ord1.oditnr, ord1.odredt, itm.imdesc  
FROM orderdetails ord1
INNER JOIN orderdetails ord2
  ON ord1.odbcsn = ord2.odbcsn 
LEFT JOIN items itm ON ord1.oditnr = itm.imitnr
WHERE ord2.oditnr = '1022925'  
   AND ord2.odredt >= (CURDATE() - interval 60 day  + 0) 
   AND ord1.odbcsn = '11677'  
ORDER BY odredt desc ;


-- Updated this query
    SELECT ord1.oditnr, ord1.odredt, itm.imdesc  
    FROM orderdetails ord1
    LEFT JOIN orderdetails ord2
      ON ord1.odbcsn = ord2.odbcsn 
    LEFT JOIN items itm ON ord1.oditnr = itm.imitnr
    WHERE ord2.oditnr = '2521809'  
       AND ord2.odredt >= (CURDATE() - interval 60 day  + 0) 
       AND ord1.odbcsn = '11677'  
    ORDER BY odredt desc ;
```

UPDATE: I adjusted the bottom query to change the INNER JOIN to a LEFT JOIN. However, unlike the query posted by the OP, this version returns an empty set if the ord2.oditnr is not found - which intuitively makes sense - if the order number is not found, don't return any row. Without a sub-query of some sort, there really isn't a way to return a set based on a non

At the very least, the top query matches the OPs output.

Comment: I'm afraid an inner join won't help find records that _don't exist_.

Comment: this query works fine for converting the WHERE EXISTS.

Comment: I would also like  a query i can use with any item number for the NOT EXIST.             for example. customer (11677) actually bought the item(1025926) so the NOT EXISTS query correctly returns no results.  http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/357b5/6